# Maximum update depth exceeded when counting values of array in state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-bootstrap

im trying to count a value from state.map

```
checkIFvat(value){
    if(value > 0) {
        this.setState({totalVat: this.state.totalVat + value});
        return ("*")
    }
}

{this.state.invoiceDetails.map(obj => {
    return (
    <tr>
        <td>
            {obj.quantity * obj.salePrice} {this.checkIFvat(obj.vatValue)}
        </td>
    </tr>
);
})}

        <p>Vat 11%{this.state.totalVat}</p>
```

what should i do to let this works

Comment: this's causing the problem `this.checkIFvat(obj.vatValue)`

Comment: You shouldn't be iteratively setting the state from the render portion of the react lifecycle, as you can see by your error. Condense this into a sum function, which sets the state once after it maps the invoiceDetails

Comment: thanks @SterlingArcher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.checkIFvat(obj.vatValue)`is causing that error, as your are setting state in render. Create a function to calculate vat where you set your `invoiceDetails`.

```
calculateTotalVat = (items) => {

  if (!items) {
    return 0;
  }

  let totalVat = 0;

  items.forEach(obj => {
    totalVat += obj.vatValue;
  });

  return totalVat;
}

this.setState({
 invoiceDetails: data,
 totalVat: this.calculateTotalVat(data),
});
```

Then in your map check if `obj.vatValue > 0` display `*` or blank string

```
{this.state.invoiceDetails.map(obj => {
  return (
  <tr>
      <td>
          {obj.quantity * obj.salePrice} {obj.vatValue > 0 ? '*' : ''})}
      </td>
  </tr>
);
})}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling this.checkIFvat() (that is calling this.setState) inside render method so as result you are getting maximum update issue.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you need to store the total vat value as component's state you can use following solution:

```
  render() {
    const { invoiceDetails } = this.state;

    const totalVat = invoiceDetails.reduce((acc, invoiceDetail) => {
      return acc + invoiceDetail.vatValue;
    }, 0);

    const rows = invoiceDetails.map(obj => {
      return (
        <tr>
          <td>
            {obj.quantity * obj.salePrice} {obj.vatValue > 0 && "*"}
          </td>
        </tr>
      );
    });

    return (
      <>
        {rows}
        <p>Vat 11%{totalVat}</p>
      </>
    );
  }
```